# How to customize infoSpots in Panolens JS from the standard arrow symbol to a text or an image

Tags: javascript

The below has two 360 images, one click takes you to panel1 and another back to pano5. The infospots are in the position (-2134.06, 16.30, 890.14) and (-3136.06, 296.30, -4290.14). I am trying customize these spot to say "Go Inside" and "Go Outside". Tried everything, the changes either don't show up or the entire Panolens wont work.

```
const panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama( 'images/panel1.jpeg' );
const panorama2 = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama('images/pano5.jpg');
let imageContainer=document.querySelector('.image-container')

var infospotPositions = [
    new THREE.Vector3(-2134.06, 16.30, 890.14),
    new THREE.Vector3(-3136.06, 296.30, -4290.14),
];

const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
    container: imageContainer,
    autoRotate: true,
    autoRotateSpeed: 0.3,
    controlBar: true,


});

panorama.link( panorama2, infospotPositions[0]);
panorama2.link( panorama, infospotPositions[1]);


viewer.add( panorama, panorama2);
```

I tried customizing this way:

````
var infospot1 = new PANOLENS.Infospot(300);
infospot1.position.copy(infospotPositions[0]);
infospot1.element.innerHTML = 'Go Inside'; // Set the text content directly

infospot1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  viewer.setPanorama(panorama2);
});```

The change doesn't seem to show up. Please help.
````